# Right way to dispose page with WebView in a MAUI app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, maui

I have a MAUI Android app (sample) with 2 pages, 1 home page and 1 page containing WebView. From home page user can go to the WebView page and open a site, come back to the home page and again go to WebView page to open other site, user can do this multiple times.

After few such cycles, in `edge://inspect/#devices` I see multiple instances of the WebView and with page navigating away the WebView is not going away, I am concerned that this is causing memory leak.

[image]

I see the WebView class does not has any close/dispose/destroy kind of methods. What is the proper way to close the page containing WebView so that all resources are properly released?

I have attached the sample app which reproduces the issue. Pasting some code snippets for quick reference -

[MauiAppWebView.zip](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/files/12902037/MauiAppWebView.zip)

```
// How page with WebView is being opened
private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> siteList = new List<string>() { "https://www.google.com", "https://www.bing.com", "https://www.youtube.com", "https://www.microsoft.com" };
    Random rnd = new Random();
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage1(siteList[rnd.Next(0, siteList.Count)]));
}

// How site is being loaded in WebView
public NewPage1(string site)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webview.Source = site;
}
// Page exit/back handling
private void GoBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Steps to Reproduce -

1. Build and start the app attached in the zip on Android device.
2. Click on 'Click me'
3. New page with site loads, click 'Go Back'
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 few times.
5. Open edge://inspect/#devices
6. Look for the device, you'll see all instances of WebView

**Things I have tried so far -**

1. While existing/back the page, set `webview` to `null`.
2. Used singleton instance of `WebView` in the page.

None of these things helped, and in edge inspect I still see all the previous webview pages.

Please suggest on what is the right way to dispose the page and webview.

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said. And I found there is a known issue about this problem [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18021).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I only created that issue, since I did not get any traction there, I am posting on StackOverflow for help.

Comment: He didn't even notice they're the same author LOL